# Find the general solution of the given differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the general solution of the given differential equation

$$\frac{y^2}{2}-2ye^t+(y-e^t)\frac{dy}{dt}=0$$

So we are learning about exact equations and the first step our professor told us to do is check the derivatives of m and n:

$$M: \frac{y^2}{2}-2ye^t $$

$$ N: y-e^t $$

Now, derivatives:

$$M: \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y}=y-2e^t$$

$$N: \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t}=e^t$$

but they are not equal, so I'm not sure what to do next or am I not able to do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rearrange the ODE we have

$$\frac{y^2}{2}+yy'=2ye^t+y'e^t$$

Multiplying both sides by $e^t$:

$$e^t\frac{y^2}{2}+e^tyy'=2ye^{2t}+y'e^{2t}\quad (*)$$

Note that

$$LHS=\frac{d}{dt}\left(e^t\frac{y^2}{2}\right),\quad RHS=\frac{d}{dt}(e^{2t}y)$$

Integrating both sides of $(*)$ gives

$$e^ty^2=2e^{2t}y+C\Rightarrow y^2-2e^ty-Ce^{-t}=0$$

Solve for $y$ gives

$$y=\frac{-(-2e^t)\pm\sqrt{4e^{2t}+4Ce^{-t}}}{2}=e^t\pm\sqrt{e^{2t}+Ce^{-t}}$$

Comment: how did you know to multiply by e$^t$ on both sides?

Comment: That trick is related to the method of integrating factor. If you want to solve an ODE of the form $y'+f(x)y=g(x)$, then multiplying both sides by $e^{\int f(x)dx}$, the LHS becomes $\frac{d}{dx}(e^{\int f(x)dx}y)$, finally integrating both sides we can get what we want. There are many examples in elementary ODE notes/textbooks. This question is more complicated and the key part is to rearrange you equation, and observe what factor you need to multiply.

Comment: understood! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Notice that

$$ \frac{1}{N} \left(\frac{\partial M}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial N}{\partial t}\right) = \frac{(y- 2e^t) - (-e^t)}{y - e^t} = 1 $$

doesn't depend on $y$

So we can define our integrating factor to be

$$ \mu(t) = \exp\left(\int \frac{1}{N} \left(\frac{\partial M}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial N}{\partial t}\right) dt\right) = \exp\left(\int dt\right) = e^t $$

Multiplying the equation by this integrating factor to get

$$ \left(\frac{y^2e^t}{2} - 2ye^{2t}\right)dt + (ye^t - e^{2t})\,dy = 0 $$

You can check to see that this equation is exact